# Using async loop in mongodb shell for updating many documents

Tags: mongodb, shell, asynchronous, mongodb-query, insert-update

I have a problem with the following query in MongoDB shell ONLY when the size of the array gets bigger, for example, more than 100 elements.

```
newPointArray   --> is an array with 500 elements
newPointArray.forEach(function(newDoc){
       //update the mongodb properties for each doc
db.getCollection('me_all_test')
.update({ '_id': newDoc._id  },
{ $set: { "properties": newDoc.properties } },
{ upsert: true });
})
```

Can someone guide me how can I run this query IN MongoDB SHELL for lager array by using an async loop or promise or...?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the exact problem?  Does the shell lag?  I would think that if you are trying to update multiple items at a time, you would use a bulk write operation.  See documentation: [Bulk Write Operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/).

Comment: @zero298 you should post the suggestion of Bulk Write Operations as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than doing individual `.update()`s, use a [`.bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkWrite) operation.  This should reduce the overhead of asking mongo to do multiple individual operations.  This is assuming that you are doing general operations.  I'm not clear on if `newPointArray` is always new points that don't exist.

Given your example, I believe your script would mimic the following:

```js
// I'm assuming this is your array (but truncated)
let newPointArray = [
    {
        _id: "1",
        properties: {
            foo: "bar"
        }
    },
    {
        _id: "2",
        properties: {
            foo: "buzz"
        }
    }
    // Whatever other points you have in your array
];

db
    .getCollection("me_all_test")
    .bulkWrite(newPointArray
        // Map your array to a query bulkWrite understands
        .map(point => {
            return {
                updateOne: {
                    filter: {
                        _id: point._id
                    },
                    update: {
                        $set: {
                            properties: point.properties
                        }
                    },
                    upsert: true
                }
            };
        }));
```

You may also want to consider setting `ordered` to false in the operation which may also have performance gains.  That would look something liked this:

```
db
    .getCollection("me_all_test")
    .bulkWrite([SOME_ARRAY_SIMILAR_TO_ABOVE_EXAMPLE], {
        ordered: false
    });
```

Comment: @ zero298: thanks a lot.Now you gave me this vision of how to use bulk write. well done :)